# unable to return slash symbol from the MS ASR (Sgrs grammar)

Tags: speech-recognition, grammar, speech, sapi

I am new to SRGS so in advance forgive me if it is too obvious to you experts, but I have found nothing so far on the subject.

What I am trying to do is when spoken "L four slash five" the MS ASR should return "L4/5".  No matter what I do I cant seem to have '/' symbol get to display.

---

```
<grammar version="1.0" 
     xml:lang="en-US" 
     mode="voice"
     xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/06/grammar"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.w3.org/2001/06/grammar 
                         http://www.w3.org/TR/speech-grammar/grammar.xsd"
     xmlns:sapi="http://schemas.microsoft.com/Speech/2002/06/SRGSExtensions"
     sapi:alphabet="x-microsoft-ups" 
     root="medical" >

<rule id="l45" scope="public">
        <item>
    <token sapi:display="L4/5"> L four slash five </token>
  </item>
</rule>

<rule id="medical" scope="public" sapi:dynamic="true">
    <one-of>
        <item><ruleref uri="#l45"/></item> 
    </one-of>
</rule>
```

I have tried sapi:display="L4/5" instead of sapi:display="L4/5" same thing.  The ASR returns only "L4".  Just for the heck of it I tried removing slash eg. sapi:display="L45" the ASR promptly returns correct text: "L45".
The requirement here is to be able to do this all in Srgs XML file (no compiled code should be involved).

What am I missing?  I am really stuck.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

After looking at the SRGS specification [SRGS spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/speech-grammar/#S4.10), it certainly is not clear. The closest thing I found in it was about tags and ambiguity.

You could try tag and out as described in the [MSDN designing grammar rules](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj127913.aspx)

The example they give is this:

```
<rule id="participants">
    <one-of>
      <item> Nancy Anderson <tag> out="NanAnd" </tag> </item>
      <item> Alan Brewer <tag> out="abrewer" </tag> </item>
      <item> Oliver Lee <tag> out="olilee" </tag> </item>
      <item> April Reagan <tag> out="areagan" </tag> </item>
      <item> Cindy White <tag> out="cwhite" </tag> </item>
      <item> Ken Kwok <tag> out="kkwok" </tag> </item>
    </one-of>
  </rule>
```

Answer (score 0):

`<token sapi:display>` is a Microsoft extension to SRGS, and I strongly suspect that it's implemented by converting the token into Display/Lexical/Pronunciation form, whose only documentation I can find is in the comment for the LEXDELIMITER attribute for the [SAPI grammar format](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms723634(v=vs.85).aspx):

> LEXDELIMITER (optional): The LEXDELIMITER attribute specifies the
>   delimiter for explicit lexicon entries specified in the grammar. 
>   Grammar authors are able to specify the lexicon information by using a
>   special sequence of characters. The sequence of characters is:

```
        LEXDELIMITERDisplayFormLEXDELIMITERLexicalFormLEXDELIMITERPronunciation;
```

and the default value is '/'.   The pronunciation form is optional, and may be omitted.

So, a string in the grammar that has the form `/4/four/fo eh er;` is *one* token that will be returned in the recognized text as '4', will be found in the lexicon via 'four' and will be pronounced as 'fo eh er'.   This is often used in Japanese, where the display form is in Kanji, and the lexical form is in Hiragana or Katakana.

Now, it should be straightforward to see why `<token sapi:display="L4/5">` doesn't quite work - the display element is getting stripped down to fit in the token syntax.

To make this work, you would need to have the equivalent of the SAPI `LEXDELIMITER` attribute in an SRGS grammar, and I don't see one in the Microsoft documentation.